# Do all (not including partioned) Redisson features work regardless of clustering mode?

Tags: redis, redisson

Hi looking at the docs and apart where it's obviously stated that a feature is partitioned, does for example a regular Redisson map or AtomicLong work regardless of the Redis cluster modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all Redisson objects work in Redis cluster.